# Using ant, find files matching a regular expression

Tags: java, maven, ant, izpack

I have a directory containing 2 sub directories one of this directory has a file called

dictionary_FR.properties
dictionary_EN.properties

I want to search for these files with ant

Thanks

Comment: Why? For what purpose?

Comment: I want to copy a folder needed in other module

Answer (score 1):

```
<fileset dir="loc_of_dir_containing_the_sub_dirs" id="xyz">
      <include name="**/dictionary_*.properties"/>
    </fileset>

<pathconvert pathsep="," property="my_files" refid="xyz"/>
```

`${my_files}` will contain the address of all files named in the pattern `dictionary_XX.properties`.

Comment: I tried your solution but it does not work
I will show you the tree of the sub dirs
"client\com\x\y\z\translations"
I need to search for files exist in the translations dir client is the main directory

Comment: my_files property was empty

Comment: retry the code now, i've made a correction. and also, please do post your own code, just in case there's some other error..